# Setting cookies in Wordpress

Tags: functions, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie on my site and wanna switch the style sheets using this cookie.

I've tested a normal function but it does not work.
I've put below code into my `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'cookiecheck');

function cookiecheck(){         
    setcookie( 'cookiename', 'cookievalue', time() + 3600, 'mysite.net/sites/site1/', 'mysite.net/sites/site1/');       
}
```

After I add this code if i check my `cookies` tab using firefox `developer` tools I don't see a cookie called `cookiecheck`

Why is this?
How to set a cookie in a wordpress site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
setcookie( 'cookiename', 'cookievalue', time() + 3600, 'mysite.net/sites/site1/', 'mysite.net/sites/site1/');
```

to

```
setcookie( 'cookiename', cookievalue, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);`
```

`COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN` are WP constants now, but the codex is not updated yet.